# .Net + SQL: Convert SQL Server query to Linq (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on a -more or less- complex Linq query where I need to do something that should be stupid and simple, but today I'm off. I need to count repeated IDs from a related table.

To make it short, I'll paste here only the relevant part of my query is SQL format.

I need to write it in Linq (I've done some attempts with no success before asking, but it's not worth to paste them):

```
select 
    (select count(*)
        from ps p
        where p.finca_id = f.finca_id
       ) as ps_count, f.*
from finca f
```

Comment: `context.Fincas.Select(f=>new { finca = f,  count = f.pses.Count())` (if I correctly guess models, because you didn't show them in the query)

Comment: Thank you very much @Selvin, you were right. Sorry I'm distracted today and have written the answer myself without letting you putting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something very silly:

```
var q =
    from
        finca in db.finca

    select new FincaViewModel
    {
        whatever,
        pscount = finca.ps.Count()
    };
```

Sorry if I was not clear in the question, but in my EF model "finca" entity has a collection of "ps" entity elements, and I didn't realize.

Edit 1:

Removed Where as suggested by @Selvin:

Replaced

pscount = finca.ps.Count()(ps => ps.finca_id == finca.finca_id)

by

pscount = finca.ps.Count()

Comment: `finca.ps` should contain only `pses` which are connected with given `finca` so `Where(...)` seems to be redundant

Comment: Yes @Selvin, I realized before, but forgot to delete it. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: There are tools that help you to convert SQL into LINQ nowadays. One of them is [LINQ Me Up](https://www.linqmeup.com)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @EeKay, and sorry for the delay in the response.